# Data encryption stoppped working in Eloquent model after upgrading to Laravel 5.5

Tags: model, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm using [elocryptfive](https://github.com/delatbabel/elocryptfive) for encrypting some fields in database - in a nutshell it's a PHP trait that encrypts attributes marked as encryptable before they are written into database and decrypts them when showing them to user (with `getAttribute` and other such methods).

Simpler version of it can be found in [this laracasts discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/encrypting-model-data).

There weren't any problems when using Laravel versions earlier than 5.5. After upgrading the site to laravel 5.5 I've noticed that values that were supposed to be encrypted, were instead presented in plaintext.

I've filed issue in package github account, asking for help. In the meantime I've tried few things:

1. added elocryptfive package in freshly installed laravel 5.2 and 5.4 - encryption worked correctly
2. did the same in stock laravel 5.5 - the values were encrypted only after first save, and stored decrypted after every subsequent update
3. I haven't found anything related in forums/laracasts yet

It seems that it could be related to some changes between 5.4 and 5.5, I've already tried comparing few classes in `Eloquent` namespace but gave up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing once again the changes between 5.4 and 5.5 tags in laravel/framework package I found out the reason in `getDirty` method of 
`src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php` trait.

In laravel 5.4 there was:

`foreach ($this->attributes as ...`

then in 5.5 it was changed to:

`foreach ($this->getAttributes() as ...`

As `getAttributes` method is one of those which decrypt data, it looks that for now the most sensible solution will be to override `getDirty()` either in encrypting trait or in application models using it.

The modified method would look like this:

```
public function getDirty()
{
    $dirty = [];

    foreach ($this->attributes as $key => $value) {
        if (! $this->originalIsEquivalent($key, $value)) {
                    $dirty[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $dirty;
}
```